# zoom controller not working in webview in android

Tags: android, zooming, android-webview

I am suffering from a strange problem in order to implement `WebView` in android. I am trying to load html5 supported web page in my `WebView`, but the problem is default zoom controller is not working in `WebView`. 
i tried with the following code.

```
webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webview.invokeZoomPicker();
```

Can any body help regarding this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this line also

```
WebSettings setting = wView.getSettings();
        setting.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        setting.setSupportZoom(true);
```

if work or not please reply